# How do i make spal.js work again, i use it to display error messages for my web page form validation for some reason they dont seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, visual-web-developer, error-messages-for

I've used them(popper.js & spal.js) before to display error messages on my website form validation.
They worked fine then but right now they're not

I've rewritten the code over again but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: The title should be concise. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the error is guys, I did not use the specific submit button name, I've fixed it and everything is working fine now :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).